# Magento custom extension not showing layout template

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

This is my controller

```
<?php 
class Karmick_Refer_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Earn Money'));
         $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function getCodeAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();

         $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public function checkAction(){
        die('Hello');
    }

}
?>
```

This is my layout xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
<default>
    <remove name="left"/>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/karmick/check.css</name></action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</default>
<refer_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="refer/refer" name="refer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>karmick/refer.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
</reference>
</refer_index_index>
</layout>
```

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Karmick_Refer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Karmick_Refer>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <karmick_refer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Karmick_Refer</module>
                    <frontName>refer</frontName>
                </args>
            </karmick_refer>
        </routers>


<layout>
<updates>
<karmick_refer>
<file>karmick/refer.xml</file>
</karmick_refer>
</updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
<global>
<models>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Model</class>
<resourceModel>refer_mysql4</resourceModel>
</refer>
<refer_mysql4>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Model_Mysql4</class>
<entities>
<refer>
<table>karmick_refer</table>
</refer>
</entities>
</refer_mysql4>
</models>
<resources>
<refer_write>
<connection>
<use>core_write</use>
</connection>
</refer_write>
<refer_read>
<connection>
<use>core_read</use>
</connection>
</refer_read>
<refer_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Karmick_Refer</module>
        <class>Karmick_Refer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
</refer_setup>
<connection>
    <use>core_setup</use>
</connection>
</resources>
<helpers>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Helper</class>
</refer>
</helpers>
<blocks>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Block</class>
</refer>
</blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

But still my template file is not including..   When i am giving this code in  Then template is coming..

Any idea what i am doing wrong??

Comment: Put your `config.xml` here

Comment: I update my question.. please check

Comment: Clear cache or disable them

Comment: already disabled

Comment: try replacing with this <block type="refer/index" name="refer_index">

Comment: but my block file name is Refer.php

Comment: try this `<block type="refer/refer" name="refer" template="karmick/refer.phtml">`

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 15: parser error

Comment: Check your error log.This error means there is an error in your xml format

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
<default>
<remove name="left"/>
 <reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/karmick/check.css</name></action>
    </reference>
 <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
 </default>
 <refer_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="refer" template="karmick/refer.phtml"/>
</reference>
</refer_index_index>
</layout>
add above code in layout.xml file

Comment: This error is comming when i m putting your code @Rohit

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 8: parser error : expected '>'  new error @Abdul

Comment: change `refer_index_index` to `karmick_refer_index_index`

Comment: Thank you very much @AmitBera. I was really frustrated with that. only your solution work. Thank you very much again

Comment: Can you please tell me that why i need to add the company name?? caz as per all modules they are not including company name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `refer_index_index` to `karmick_refer_index_index`.

In `config.xml` you have define `karmick_refer`as  your **frontname identifier** for this extension.

```
  <routers>
            <karmick_refer> <!  frontName Identifier -->
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Karmick_Refer</module>
                    <frontName>refer</frontName>
                </args>
            </karmick_refer>
        </routers>
```

Also whenevr **a page layout load** then a  **unique handle  are created** which are  same as below format

'`FrontNamaIdentifier_ControllerName_ActionName`' .

So for your case it is `karmick_refer_index_index`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your layout xml:

```
<refer_index_index>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="refer/refer" name="refer" template="karmick/refer.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </refer_index_index>
```

Comment: I have just updated my answer please use above code and let me know

Comment: Not worked :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<refer_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="refer/refer" name="refer" template="karmick/refer.phtml" />
    </reference>
</refer_index_index>
```

Comment: Not working Prashant.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in `config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Karmick_Refer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Karmick_Refer>
    </modules>             
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <refer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Karmick_Refer</module>
                    <frontName>refer</frontName>
                </args>
            </refer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <karmick_refer>
                    <file>karmick/refer.xml</file>
                </karmick_refer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
<global>
<models>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Model</class>
<resourceModel>refer_mysql4</resourceModel>
</refer>
<refer_mysql4>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Model_Mysql4</class>
<entities>
<refer>
<table>karmick_refer</table>
</refer>
</entities>
</refer_mysql4>
</models>
<resources>
<refer_write>
<connection>
<use>core_write</use>
</connection>
</refer_write>
<refer_read>
<connection>
<use>core_read</use>
</connection>
</refer_read>
<refer_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Karmick_Refer</module>
        <class>Karmick_Refer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
</refer_setup>
<connection>
    <use>core_setup</use>
</connection>
</resources>
<helpers>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Helper</class>
</refer>
</helpers>
<blocks>
<refer>
<class>Karmick_Refer_Block</class>
</refer>
</blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Add bellow code in block file `Refer.php`

```
<?php
class Karmick_Refer_Block_Refer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }                  
}
```